# Ordinal exponentiation of limit ordinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Prove that If $a$ is a limit ordinal and $p$ and $q$ are finite ordinals, then $(ap)^q$ = $a^q$$p^q$.

In my book, the right side of the equality is written as $a^qp$, but i think its typo since equality does not hold for the case $q=0$ and $p\ge1$.

Comment: The book's version is the correct one for $q>0$.

Comment: Can you tell me the name of the book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is correct, *except* in the case that $q=0$ and $p\neq 1$. One result you might want to prove is that for any limit ordinal $\lambda$ and any non-$0$ finite ordinal $p$, we have $p\cdot\lambda=\lambda$. From that, associativity of multiplication, and the fact that $0\cdot\alpha=0=\alpha\cdot 0$ for all $\alpha$, the book's equality follows readily by induction for non-$0$ finite $q$.

Comment: I was only focusing on the limit ordinal... Thanks